# Documentation generator tool for BOTH Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, documentation, documentation-generation, code-documentation

Do you know about a tool to easily create documentation for both JavaScript and PHP code?

Something that takes comments in code similar to the one shown below:

```
/**********************************************************
This function does something special...

param1: ...
param2:

RETURNED VALUES:
...
**********************************************************/
function something(...)
{
   ...
```

And convert these into HTML files (maybe with a frameset menu on the left).
**Don't need for the same syntax shown above,** it's only an example to explain of what I'm talking about.

Would like only one tool so once I learned the syntax to write documentation, i can use **the same documentation syntax for both PHP and JavaScript.**

It would be nice if the tool was a binary (.exe) or a Java code, with **no need to install PERL or PYTHON.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://doxygen.org) can handle PHP out-of-the-box, and [helper scripts](http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html) are available to enable its use with Javascript (this does require Perl, however).

Answer (score -1):

No offense, but the world of web development (especially PHP) is still a mainly Unix-based world. If you're automatically discounting anything that's based on Perl, Python, or another scripting language (like PHP!), your options dramatically drop, especially if you don't want to pay for it.

You should be able to install Perl binaries and then just run a script...

Comment: I0m not discoutning PHP, I have it installed for my day time job. I'm lazy I don't have time now to install PERL and waste 1 week to understand how it works. Could you suggest a link with an easy tutorial on how to install it?

Comment: Well unfortunately I can't tell you a thing about how to run Perl on Windows. If you go to http://www.perl.org/get.html there are Windows binary installers. No need to understand "how" it works... it's just like any other scripting interpreter... open a command prompt, type "perl" followed by the name of the script, and it runs...

Comment: I don't think that you're limiting yourself. You're wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators#Operating_system_support 
It's mostly Windows based for the generators.